# How to handle relative imports with Flask and Docker?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose, python-import

### Question

I have an app - let's call it **foobar**. It's built using **Flask**, **PostgreSQL**, and **docker-compose**.

It builds and runs successfully. But when I open it in a browser, I get the following `ImportError`:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "app.app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/usr/src/app/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

The error is raised from a relative import in `app/__init__.py`:

```
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
```

I know that all of the app files were copied to the container - I can see them in both the Flask debugger and via ssh. So here's my question: ***Why isn't Flask detecting config.py? And how can I fix it?***

---

### Context

**File Structure**

```
foobar
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   └── requirements.txt
├── docker-compose.yml
└── init.sql
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    app:
        build: ./app
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "postgres:13"
        volumes:
            - "./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"
```

**/app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV FLASK_ENV development
ENV FLASK_APP app
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

**app/**init**.py**

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI

app = Flask(__name__)

# configure database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine) # automap existing tables to db.Model

class Foo(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['foos']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Foo %r>' % self.name


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    count = db.session.query(Foo).count()
    return f'Hello World! I have {count} foos stored.'
```

---

***Note*** - I know it's an issue with `sys.path`. The files in `app` are copied to the working directory for the `app` container, and I can successfully import the module in the Flask debugger like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
from . import config
```

Comment: have you tried `from app.config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`, or move your config file outside folder `app`?

Comment: I have tried `from app.config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`, and it does not work.

Also, I don't want to move `config.py` outside of `app` - I'll eventually add more modules and files in the `app` directory, and I'll need relative imports to work then.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - the solution was to install `foobar` as a local package when building the Docker image. This ensured that `/usr/src/app` was added to `PATH`, which fixed my relative imports.

I changed the directory structure:

```
foobar
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── foobar
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   └── database.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── setup.py
├── docker-compose.yml
└── init.sql
```

And I added the following line to `/app/Dockerfile`:

```
RUN ["pip", "install", "-e", "."]
```